# Define a column with a default value in Liquibase

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I am trying to call `current_timestamp` function for a column in Postgres using liquibase, but I have no idea how to do that. Can I do it inside SQL tag? I would appreciate if anybody can help me with a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you you will have to do is use changelog parameters and define a "now" or "current_timestamp" parameter that is replaced per database type.

At the top of your `<databaseChangeLog>`, normally just outside your `<changeset>`, add per-database definitions of the property like:

```
  <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="postgresql"/>
```

then in your changesets use

```
  <column name="Join_date" defaultValueFunction="${now}"/>
```

Notice the use of defaultValueFunction that will let liquibase know not to parse it as a date or quote it.

This will work well too:

```
<column name="actiondate" type="timestamp with time zone" defaultValueComputed="current_timestamp"/>
```

Comment: in the changeset column. is not a need to set the type of column?